# Subtraction from number works only once in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, numbers, subtraction

I have this html:
`<strong ng-bind-html="CTRL.maximum_score"></strong>`

in there i have some number - now, on some click action i'm trying to subtract -1 from this number, so i do this:

```
this.minimum_score = this.$sce.trustAsHtml(this.minimum_score - 1);
```

or

```
this.minimum_score = this.$sce.trustAsHtml(--this.minimum_score);
```

the problem is that this action fires only once, for example if i have 7 i can subtract to 6 but not more 5,4,3... .If i'm trying to add +1 to this number everything works fine. What is going on?

Comment: You don't need `$sce.trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html` if your `minimum_score` is just a number. Just use `ng-bind="CTRL.maximum_score"`

Comment: ok, fine and thanks, but this is not solving my problem

Comment: Any chance you can dump this into a plunk?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do and it would be easier if we could see it.